# Mocking test class Spring camel

Tags: junit, apache-camel, spring-test

I am new to camel. I am trying to write a test case.

```
public class A
{
   private B b;

   public void update(String s){
   //calling some methods on B
   .....
   }
}
```

Test class

```
public class TestA extends CamelSpringTestSupport
{
  private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext xmlAppContext;

  @Test
  public void testA()
  {
    String xml = "some xml";
    Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("direct:incomingxml");
    Exchange inExchange = endpoint.createExchange();
    inExchange.getIn().setBody(xml);
    inExchange.setPattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly);
    template.send(endpoint, inExchange);
  }

   @Override
   protected AbstractApplicationContext createApplicationContext()
   {
       xmlAppContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath:/test-camel-context.xml"); 
       return xmlAppContext;
   }
}
```

spring bean xml

```
 <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

        <route>
            <from uri="direct:incomingxml"/>
            <to uri="bean:classA?method=update"/>
        </route>

      </camelContext>

       <bean id="b" class="B">
       </bean>

       <bean id="classA" class="A">
           <constructor-arg index="0" ref="b" />
       </bean>
```

There are couple of test cases pre-written using real objects. Is there any way I can mock this class B, gets injected in class A and mock few methods? I want to do in my test case only so that pre-written test cases remain unaffected?

Comment: One way would be to add a setter to class A. Then in your new tests you would set your mocked object B to A.

Comment: That will be affecting the rest of test cases as well since the context is loaded only once while starting up.

Comment: Not really. The context is loaded once, and the B bean is injected with the definition from the XML. But when you get into your test, you can still replace A's B object with the mock. If you do that in your test case only your test case will be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding a setter in you class A.

The application context will be loaded and A's B object will be injected by the bean declared in the XML but you can still override it with a mock of B by calling the newly defined setter in your test.

Then by doing that, B's mock will be used in your test and no the bean. The other test cases will not be affected.